# After generating devise:views my sign_up page doesnt trigger any action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my demo app for studying Rails - with a model `user` and one `post`, I installed the `gem Devise`. I enabled then Devise on the User model in terminal with `rails g devise User`, ran `rake db:migrate`, restarted `rails s`.
When i first used the localhost:3000/users/sign_up (this is my URL for the registration of a new user), I could successfully create a new user, Devise made a notice flash etc etc. All went smoothly.
My issue started when I wanted to customize the layout of the sign_up page. 
I then proceeded to `rails g devise:views`. I could change the layout of the view `devise/registration/new.html.erb` corresponding to the URL `/users/signup`, but the page did not trigger any action any more.
I see in the `rails s` that the `/users/sign_up` is processed by `devise/registrations#new`, but even if I try to signup with different email addresses, no notices are flashed anymore and the page doesnt change, it will always show the signup form.
Here is the code `https://github.com/Adsidera/Indielitblog`
Please sorry if my question seems silly, I am just a beginner... :(
Thanks in advance
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently it was due to a form-control html tag that i added and that somehow interfered with the devise controller. 
Keeping the customization only to a div container-fluid and few essential changes solved the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

just verified you had a form_for inside the html form tag, by removing the form tag resolved the issue:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<form class="form-signin">
 <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
...
  <% end %>
```

to just

```
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign up</h2>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

If you want to change the class to the form_for helper you can try `:html => {:class => "foo"}`

best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks! indeed it was the form class causing the issue! Thanks for the further tip, cheers!